# How to disable transparency in knitr plots?

Tags: r, pdf-generation, knitr

I have a LaTeX/knitr document that I need to convert to PDF/A, but I'm getting errors about transparency being used (which is not allowed in PDF/A). I traced it back to the background fills of the boxplots that I'm generating in R via knitr. Regardless of whether I use "pdf", "cairo_pdf" or "tikzDevice" as the output device, the same error results.

The Tikz output includes the following:

```
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\path[use as bounding box,fill=fillColor,fill opacity=0.00] (0,0) rectangle (505.89,325.21);
```

Manually removing the `fill opacity=0.00` part and rerunning only `pdflatex` gets rid of the message for a particular graph, so I'm pretty sure that's the cause. However, I'd prefer to make the change in the source file (R code), so I don't have to manually make this fix every time the source changes and the intermediate files are regenerated.

Does anyone know the magic option to feed `bxp` or `par` in R that would translate into an opacity of 1.0, or, better still, specify no fill at all? (The fill is completely unnecessary, given that it's a white background being placed on an empty part of a page.)

(BTW, I tried `bg=NA` in the `bxp` call, and `par(bg=NA)` before, and neither had any effect. For that matter, using `"red"` also had no effect, so that doesn't seem to be the right option.)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the `bg` in the graphics parameters (`par=`) only applies to objects within the plot (like the boxes in a boxplot). The background for the whole plot is set in knitr's `dev.args` chunk option, e.g., globally:

```
opts_chunk$set(dev='tikz', dev.args=list(bg="white"))
```

or at the start of a particular chunk. It appears there's no way to drop the fill option entirely (there's a "TODO" item in the [tikzDevice source code](https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/blob/master/src/tikzDevice.c)), but changing it to `"white"` has eliminated the PDF/A validation errors, with no visible effect on the document. Once my thesis is in, maybe I can submit a patch for this. :-)